# Can't create conda environment with R ver 3.4.1

Tags: r, anaconda

I want to use specific .py script(LEfSe) for work.
This script requires python 2.7 and R 3.4.1.

So i tried to create conda environment with r 3.4.1 and python 2.7.

```
conda create -n lefse r=3.4.1 python=2.7
```

But the following messages was printed.

---

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other:

Package r-spatial conflicts for:
r-recommended==3.4.1 -> r-spatial
Package r-class conflicts for:
r-recommended==3.4.1 -> r-class
Package libgcc conflicts for:
r-base==3.4.1 -> libgcc
Package readline conflicts for:
r-base==3.4.1 -> readline
Package ncurses conflicts for:
r-base==3.4.1 -> ncurses=5.9
Package r-base conflicts for:
r-recommended==3.4.1 -> r-base==3.4.1
Package libxml2 conflicts for:
r-base==3.4.1 -> libxml2
Package icu conflicts for:
r-base==3.4.1 -> icu=54
Package r-mgcv conflicts for:
r-recommended==3.4.1 -> r-mgcv
Package r-kernsmooth conflicts for:
r-recommended==3.4.1 -> r-kernsmooth
Package pango conflicts for:
r-base==3.4.1 -> pango=1.40
Package r-matrix conflicts for:
r-recommended==3.4.1 -> r-matrix
Package r-rpart conflicts for:
r-recommended==3.4.1 -> r-rpart
Package jpeg conflicts for:
r-base==3.4.1 -> jpeg=9
Package curl conflicts for:
r-base==3.4.1 -> curl
Package zlib conflicts for:
r-base==3.4.1 -> zlib
Package r-nlme conflicts for:
r-recommended==3.4.1 -> r-nlme
Package pcre conflicts for:
r-base==3.4.1 -> pcre=8.39
Package xz conflicts for:
r-base==3.4.1 -> xz=5.2
Package r-boot conflicts for:
r-recommended==3.4.1 -> r-boot
Package r-survival conflicts for:
r-recommended==3.4.1 -> r-survival
Package gsl conflicts for:
r-base==3.4.1 -> gsl
Package r-foreign conflicts for:
r-recommended==3.4.1 -> r-foreign
Package r-codetools conflicts for:
r-recommended==3.4.1 -> r-codetools
Package bzip2 conflicts for:
r-base==3.4.1 -> bzip2
Package r-nnet conflicts for:
r-recommended==3.4.1 -> r-nnet
Package tk conflicts for:
r-base==3.4.1 -> tk
Package r-lattice conflicts for:
r-recommended==3.4.1 -> r-lattice
Package _r-mutex conflicts for:
r-recommended==3.4.1 -> _r-mutex=1[build=anacondar_1]
r-base==3.4.1 -> _r-mutex=1[build=anacondar_1]
Package libpng conflicts for:
r-base==3.4.1 -> libpng[version='>=1.6.27,<1.7']
Package libtiff conflicts for:
r-base==3.4.1 -> libtiff
Package r-cluster conflicts for:
r-recommended==3.4.1 -> r-cluster
Package r-mass conflicts for:

---

How could i solve this error message? I think installing r 3.4.1 makes the problem. When i didn't specify r 3.4.1, the error message was not printed.

Comment: When you don't choose to specify a version for `r`, what version do you get (e.g., show output for `conda list`).

Comment: Alternatively, if you need R v 3.4.1, do you also need to be using Python 2.7. It's a good recommendation to use python 3. I would suggest just running `conda create -n lefse r=3.4.1`. This will automatically select a version of Python that is suitable for your chosen R version

Comment: @s8129 Thank you for reply. i ran the command which you said, ```conda create -n lefse r=3.4.1``` but conda still printed 'incompatible with each other' like the above message.